# Blender "double click" or "Open With" does not open .obj located on desktop

Tags: file-format

I have noticed that if I double click a .obj file on my desktop(which has the blender logo) it opens blender, but the file was not correctly loaded. Here is a picture showing the scene after the double click:

[image]

I also did some reading and saw that this may be caused by the Import/Export Wavefront .obj not being enabled...so I checked that, too.

[image]

It appears as though the only way that I can load a model into Blender is if I go through File -> Import -> Wavefront .obj. I could do that, but it really staggers my workflow when I have to go through all that instead of just double clicking the .obj file on my desktop. **Is there a workaround for this? How can I fix this?**

I'm using file-format as a tag because I don't know what else to put this under.

Comment: see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34477/can-i-use-blender-as-a-photo-and-video-viewer

Comment: this is the normal behavior of blender, the file has blender logo because you changed your system settings to open that type of file with blender but it doesn't work this way

Comment: Also related: [Is it possible to associate non-blend files with Blender?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32036/is-it-possible-to-associate-non-blend-files-with-blender)

Comment: Blender can't open OBJ files or any other 3D file format directly, besides the native .blend files.

OBJ files can only be imported, for that you must have the mentioned addon enabled **and** explicitly use the *File > Import > Obj* menu option, not double click on the OBJ file.

Your obj file probably shows a blender file because you manually associated the file format with blender possible through *Right Click Menu > Open With > Blender* and have the option "Always use this application" enabled, but that doesn't mean that Blender can open it successfully